# Javascript Submenu Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu

Disclaimer! ... I am not real keen on front end development.
I have a nav menu that has two sub-menus. I am using the Symfony 3 framework for the application, so twig is involved. My base template has the navigation code so it should be available on all extended twig pages. Here is the html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <!-- Main menu -->
    <li class="current"><a href="{{ path('admin_dashboard') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('contact_emails') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></i> Emails</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('users_table') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Users</a></li>
    <li class="submenu">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Admin
            <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
        </a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ path('admin_profile') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}">Change Password</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Public Pages
            <span class="caret pull-right"></span>
        </a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path('about_page') }}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path('services_page') }}">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path('contact_page') }}">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the dashboard page it works just as expected.When "Admin" is clicked, the sub menu opens and the sub links are displayed. Click the other, the first sub menu closes and the other opens up.

However, when I switch to another page such as "Emails" when any of the sub menus are clicked it immediately closes. I have tried multiple ways to try and fix this but it does not seem to work. Here is the javascript for "submenu"

```
$(".submenu > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $li = $(this).parent("li");
    var $ul = $(this).next("ul");

    if($li.hasClass("open")) {
        $ul.slideUp(350);
        $li.removeClass("open");
    } else {
        $(".nav > li > ul").slideUp(350);
        $(".nav > li").removeClass("open");
        $ul.slideDown(350);
        $li.addClass("open");
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help.